How to uniform scale (link XYZ axis values)?
how can I input a value when scaling an object and have it linked in all axis (XYZ)?
For instance, I want to scale a box to 0.01. How can I scale it to 0.01 without having to input the value 0.01 three times (into X, Y nad Z)?


You just need to LMB and sweep on the 3 values, type the value and press Enter:


Thanks. I wish there was a button to link these values. Like in Photoshop.

@mts10 But why? If this method is too laborious for you, you can always use the method in my answer - then you don't even have to bother to click any input box, just enter the value right away. Seems to me even easier than Photoshop.

@mts10 As Gordon Brinkmann stated - this is even easier than Ps. Generally speaking (if you must compare the two programs), Blender tends to be more optimized for power users, with operations requiring fewer mouse clicks on interface buttons and more leveraging of keyboard shortcuts. One feature Ps borrowed from Blender is the ability to do logical operations when typing in a value. Example: 360 / 7 instead of having to do the math outside of the program and then type in that result: 51.428571 And I'm not mad at that at all. UI conventions that boost productivity are good for everyone.

Select the box, press S .01 Return. You can simply enter values when moving, rotating or scaling. And if you do not constrain it to an axis by pressing a key like X, Y or Z, the object gets scaled uniformly on all axes. This works this simple even if you have selected multiple objects, not just on the active object like entering values in the fields does.
If you want to enter a mathematical operation instead of a plain value (to avoid rounding errors for example), you can use the shortcut S followed by an equal sign = and then enter the formula, for example 2/3 or sqrt(2) etc.
The entered value shows in the top left with the scaling properties while the tool is still active:


What is the name of the keymap for S button? I changed the scale tool shortcut to E but pressing E doesnt give me a window to input a value.

You don't need a window, as I show in my question, the keys you are pressing are just S, the decimal point and the numbers, then Return (or left-click) to confirm the operation.

But what is the tool used for this? I removed S, so pressing S doesnt do anything.

@mts10 You said you changed it to E? Now do you have any shortcut for scaling or not? Just replace Swith E in my answer... I'll just leave it like that since the goal on this site is to be beneficial for everybody with a similar question, so I will not change the key to every possible custom assignment... I added a bit more to my answer if you want to use formulas instead of simple values.

I appreciate your help. Pressing E activates "Scale (resize) selected items." in the Toolbar. If I start typing 0.01 after pressing E that activates other tools. The value 0.01 is not being input into anything.

@mts10 I'm sorry, but you are doing it wrong somehow. I now changed my key to E as well, I press E . 0 1 and then Return. Typing 0.01 after E does not activate any other tools. Unless you do not enter the values directly after E, but instead you first left-click or Return and then enter the values. As I said, you do not input the value "into" something. It will just be shown at the top left of the screen where the scaling properties are shown (see my edit to the answer).

Wait a minute, it activates the tool in the toolbar? But the shortcut for that was Shift Space  >S, not just S. But what happened to the Sshortcut? This originally does not activate the tool in the toolbar... so what did you do to that? Are you doing all transformations with either activating the tools in the toolbar or changing the values in the sidepanel? Do you not use G, R and S for transformations directly in the viewport?

I'm sorry this is definitely caused by me changing the shortcuts. I also use 3dsmax, so I changed move to Q, rotate to W, scale to E. These activate the tools in the toolbar.

@mts10 Yes, I understand that now. But as I said in my last comment, just S never activated the tool in the toolbar, it was to directly scale (resize) in the viewport without having to activate the tool in the toolbar. So what did you do to that shortcut? Why is it not working anymore when what you did was changing the shortcut for activating it in the toolbar, not the one for the menu entry Object > Transform > Scale? Sorry, it is not easy to help you when you completely change all basic functions of Blender without knowing how to get them back... scaling uniformly could be so simple.

You should forget 3dsmax shortcuts and switch to Blender's, otherwise it will make things complicated

@mts10 Go to Edit > Preferences, Keymap panel, then in the search bar at the top type "Resize", it will come up with several results, find the one under Object Mode. When you press that button, it will do a uniform scale of the selected object (there are also modifiers you can press to restrict to a single axis). You scale by dragging the mouse, and commit by pressing enter or by clicking (note that how fast the object scales depends on how close your mouse is to the object when you press the button). 1/2

When activated, you can type in the values before you commit (there is no input window, but near the top, under the menu, there will be a sort of info on the XYZ scaling factors (see image above), and if you start typing, you'll see them all update (as if it was an input box), and if you press tab while doing it, you can cycle through each individual axis. Press Enter or click to commit. Here, scaling is relative to the current size of the object, while in the Transform panel the values are absolute (in terms of the "base" scale of the object). 2/2

I accidentally disabled the transform functions and they just disappeared from the keymap. I added them back manually and now I can scale by directly typing in the value.
